# Schema Name capitalization for custom entities/fields in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

MS [recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.schemaname.aspx) Pascal-case for the Schema Names, but then they don't obey the rule themselves. The custom entities and the primary fields are created by default with all-lowercase schema names, while the custom fields are Pascal-case by default. Even more, the built-in statuscode and statecode for the custom entities are all-lowercase.

Questions:

- are the schema names important down the road? There are quite a lot of external integrations coming for our CRM (C#, likely early-bound). For now I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible just to avoid potential future issues, but some colleagues think I'm over-worried and it's not worth the time.
- do you know any good reason why MS doesn't obey their own rules in some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you decided to use C# Early bound classes, you will be using crmsvcutil or some Early Bound Generator which will pull all the schema name as it is from CRM Metadata.

If the schema name changes (like on drop & recreate with different datatype) the next class file will fetch it & build error will notify you.

By seeing the [revisions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9214.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-entity-logical-name-and-entity-schema-name.aspx) nothing is going to change in near future & MS not even worrying about the rule-break.

To mention, next generation web api expects Schema Name in certain things like Navigation Properties whereas if you are going with Late binding, flat system converted lowercase Name (Logical Name) will be used.

Comment: Actually that could be part of the explanation why they have the schema name in the first place... When using the early-bound classes it makes sense to use the standard C# convention.

Answer (score 3):

I reject the pascal case advice. In my opinion, scheme name should be all lower case. This way it matches to the logical name. It prevents a lot of confusion and mistyped names, in the future.